# Smart Contract ownership change after a mistake

Tags: contract-development, ether, polygon

Big situation here. Please let me know if I was not clear enough. I mistakenly gave the wrong address to a company giving me ownership of a smart contract. It is an ownership on a collection on opensea.io.

2 mistakes here.

1. The address I gave was from a coinbase.com account, NOT a wallet.
2. The contract is on polyscan, and I gave an ETH receive hash.

My question is… how do I modify the contract to change the ownership to my wallet. Can this be done?

Comment: Most likely not possible, since it would be a huge security hole. In theory coinbase could give the same address to you on Polygon, but unfortunately you probably still couldn't send transaction from that address.

Comment: Thanks for your response Lauri! Yeah ultimately to fix this, I would need coinbase to take that ETH address and let me use it in a wallet. That isnt possible, right?

Comment: In theory it's possible, but very unlikely to happen

Comment: Is there any way to take over ownership of the smart contract? Any other way of validation aside from connecting the wallet with the same address to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the contract's code. Whatever is written there decides what is possible and what isn't.

Since you are talking about ownership, most likely it means there is one address who has special access to the contract. If this is implemented in the default way, the only way to gain this special access is to send transactions from that address. If this address has been accidentally set to be a Coinbase address, there is probably very little you can do about it.

In theory Coinbase has the private key to the address, but I'm quite sure they are not willing to compromise their security and extend their implementations to help you with your problem. If the assets in question were very valuable, then the chances are a bit above 0%, but otherwise, unfortunately, I would consider it a lost case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lauri — out of curiosity… if coinbase gave me the private key… how would I go about using it to change the ownership?

Comment: Easiest just to import the key in some wallet (metamask for example) and issue a transaction to the contract.

Comment: hey @lauri-peltonen, one other question… is it possible for opensea to modify the contract? I understand i own it via a receive address on coinbase.com. But wanted to see if OpenSea can do anything. What you said was 100% correct. After about 10+ back and forth emails, they said they cant give out private keys, etc. So they are a dead end.

Comment: ...no, Opensea can't modify the contract. They don't have any special access to the contract.